# Запуск Rails на Apache

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails, apache2, passenger

OS: Fudora 27 64bit

Несколько ранее разрабатывал сайт на php + Apache. Т.е. Апач настроен и работает. Сейчас есть желание перtйти на RoR. Как я понимаю принципы будут отличаться. На данный монет не могу привязать к Апачу RoR (По localhost:3000 стартовая страница грузится)

Делал вот по этому https://nathanhoad.net/how-to-ruby-on-rails-ubuntu-apache-with-passenger. (С той лишь разницей, что rails ставил через gem) Прописал хосты, конфиг и т.д. При заходе на желаемый доменный адрес, вместо стартовой страницы RoR грузится стартовая страница Apache.
Хотелось бы на на данный момент запустить RoR не вникая в детали (Может всё-таки я останусь на php) чтобы хоть взглянуть как выглядит процесс написания на Ruby

На даный момент вообще не понимаю к чему идет обращение. В случае сайта на php в RootDirectory ищется index.php и к нему идет обращение. А здесь несяно. И как Апач должен понять что это директория RoR а не php, ведь конфиги-то не отличаются.

Answer (score 0):

На сайте Passenger есть [отдельная страница об опознании приложений](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/ruby/app_autodetection/apache/#autodetection-algorithm).

---

Сначала он берёт значение `DocumentRoot` у хоста, в вашем гайде оно указано:

```
DocumentRoot /home/myuser/www/my_project/public # Note the 'public' directory
```

`public` из конца выкидывается. Причина или алгоритм за этим не указаны, но на практике в типичном Rails-приложении папка `public` со статическими файлами приложения (для непосредственной раздачи) расположена в корне проекта.

Остаётся `/home/myuser/www/my_project`. Его они называют "корень приложения". В корне приложения ищутся файлы, характерные для конкретных видов приложений. Правда, сейчас задокументировано обнаружение только приложений на Ruby или RoR через присутствие файла `config.ru`.

> К чему идёт обращение

К приложению, определённому в этом `config.ru` и запускаемом Apache-модулем Passenger.

> Хотелось бы на на данный момент запустить RoR не вникая в детали

Тогда вам вообще не нужны ни Apache, ни Passenger. Следуйте гайду [Getting Started](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), чтобы запустить приложение на стандартном для Rails вебсервере Puma.

---

PS: для ActionCable, компонента Ruby on Rails для общения с пользователями по Websockets, [согласно рекомендациям Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/integration_modes.html#which-mode-should-you-use) лучше не использовать Apache вообще.